# Ember-cli-dependency-checker - Invalid Version: *

Tags: json, ember.js, dependencies, ember-cli

I am trying to upgrade a project's devDependencies and encounter this error.
I can't figure out why I'm getting this error.
What package does it think is invalid? Itself?
Do I have to look in every package.json?

```
[folatt@ArkOS_Dev genesis]$ sudo ember update
Invalid Version: *
TypeError: Invalid Version: *
    at new SemVer (/home/folatt/workspace/arkos/genesis/node_modules/semver/semver.js:295:11)
    at Range.test (/home/folatt/workspace/arkos/genesis/node_modules/semver/semver.js:1049:15)
    at Function.satisfies (/home/folatt/workspace/arkos/genesis/node_modules/semver/semver.js:1098:16)
    at Function.VersionChecker.satisfies (/home/folatt/workspace/arkos/genesis/node_modules/ember-cli-dependency-checker/lib/version-checker.js:31:17)
    at Package.updateRequired (/home/folatt/workspace/arkos/genesis/node_modules/ember-cli-dependency-checker/lib/package.js:21:26)
    at Package.init (/home/folatt/workspace/arkos/genesis/node_modules/ember-cli-dependency-checker/lib/package.js:15:27)
    at new Package (/home/folatt/workspace/arkos/genesis/node_modules/ember-cli-dependency-checker/lib/package.js:4:13)
    at EmberCLIDependencyChecker.<anonymous> (/home/folatt/workspace/arkos/genesis/node_modules/ember-cli-dependency-checker/lib/dependency-checker.js:126:12)
    at Array.map (native)
    at EmberCLIDependencyChecker.readDependencies (/home/folatt/workspace/arkos/genesis/node_modules/ember-cli-dependency-checker/lib/dependency-checker.js:122:36)
```

package.json

```
{
  "author": "arkOS",
  "description": "Web management frontend for arkOS servers",
  "devDependencies": {
    "broccoli-asset-rev": "^2.4.6",
    "broccoli-funnel": "^1.0.6",
    "ember-ajax": "^2.0.1",
    "ember-cli": "^2.7.0",
    "ember-cli-app-version": "^1.0.0",
    "ember-cli-babel": "^5.1.6",
    "ember-cli-content-security-policy": "^0.5.0",
    "ember-cli-dependency-checker": "^1.3.0",
    "ember-cli-htmlbars": "^1.0.1",
    "ember-cli-htmlbars-inline-precompile": "^0.3.1",
    "ember-cli-ic-ajax": "0.2.5",
    "ember-cli-inject-live-reload": "^1.4.0",
    "ember-cli-jshint": "^1.0.5",
    "ember-cli-qunit": "^3.0.0",
    "ember-cli-release": "^0.2.9",
    "ember-cli-selectize": "^0.5.5",
    "ember-cli-sri": "^2.1.0",
    "ember-cli-uglify": "^1.2.0",
    "ember-data": "^2.7.0",
    "ember-export-application-global": "^1.0.4",
    "ember-load-initializers": "^0.5.1",
    "ember-resolver": "^2.1.0",
    "ember-uploader": "^1.1.0",
    "ember-welcome-page": "^1.0.3",
    "loader.js": "^4.0.11"
  },
  "directories": {
  "doc": "doc",
  "test": "tests"
  },
  "ember-addon": {
    "paths": [
      "lib/basicsite",
      "lib/jekyll",
      "lib/owncloud",
      "lib/radicale",
      "lib/wallabag",
      "lib/xmpp",
      "lib/cmsjs",
      "lib/duniter"
    ]
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 0.10.0"
  },
  "license": "GPLv3",
  "name": "genesis",
  "private": true,
  "repository": "",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "ember build",
    "start": "ember server",
    "test": "ember test"
  },
  "version": "0.8.0"
}
```

bower.json

```
{
  "name": "genesis",
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "codemirror": "^5.18.2",
    "ember": "^2.7.2",
    "ember-cli-shims": "^0.1.3",
    "ember-load-initializers": "^0.5.1",
    "ember-qunit-builds": "^1.0.0-beta.1",
    "ember-qunit-notifications": "^0.1.0",
    "font-awesome": "^4.6.3",
    "jquery": "^2.2.4",
    "jQuery-contextMenu": "^2.2.4",
    "lightbox2": "^2.8.2",
    "loader.js": "^4.0.11",
    "moment": "^2.14.1",
    "mozilla-fira": "4.202",
    "multiselect": "^0.9.12",
    "qunit": "^2.0.1",
    "selectize": "^0.12.3"
  }
}
```

Results of `bower install -force`
http://pastebin.com/raw/zeiLdpAA

Comment: It also check bower dependencies. Did you check it ?

Comment: Added bower.json to show none of them contain an asterisk.

Comment: instead of `bower install` you please try with `bower install -force`

Comment: @Folatt just install all that dependencies - all work fine

Comment: but you show not full list of dependencies ( in npm - there are two sections dev/others )

Comment: Which other dependencies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed ember-cli-dependency-checker after discovering that it was 1 major version behind with ember.
Then I pruned (`sudo npm prune`) the project dependencies and tried `ember build` again.

Answer (score 6):

Try this solution

**Setup**

1- `npm uninstall -g ember-cli` -- Remove old global ember-cli

2- `npm cache clean && bower cache clean`-- Clear cache

3- `npm install -g ember-cli@2.9.0-beta.1` -- Install new global ember-cli

**Project Update**

1- `rm -rf node_modules bower_components dist tmp` -- Delete temporary development folders.

2- `npm install --save-dev ember-cli@2.9.0-beta.1` -- Update project's package.json to use latest version. [You can change @2.9... to @2.8.0 as well]

3- `npm install && bower install`-- Reinstall dependencies.

It worked for me, I hope it helps you.

Comment: the problem may be that your global ember-cli version is different from the ember-cli version declared in the dev-dependencies section in the package.json file. If they match, the issue should go away